# How to work with Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is the Facebook JavaScript SDK something I download and upload to my server?  Or is it something I just call from my own JS?

I am looking at their documentation here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

But got confused half way through :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook JavaScript SDK is ran on the client's system (aka the web browser). The SDK is hosted at Facebook and you only need to include it with `<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>`. You don't need to upload it to your server.

**You use the SDK from JavaScript client-side**.

---

If it's XFBML that you find confusing: it is translated to HTML and CSS *client-side* by the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: do you know where to download it from? FB has bunch of links but I don't see one link to actually download it. :)

Comment: @Genadinik Yeah I changed it after I saw my epic mistake. It's been about a year ago already since I've used the SDK.

Comment: I understand now.  But still confused how to use it.  I have a page here for testing the FB login button and the SDK API calls: http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php but so far I have not gotten the calls right and it breaks the button lol.

Comment: @Genadinik You should only include the SDK once, and do it in the `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to upload the JavaScript SDK to your server (unless you want to stick to a particular version). If you want you can just reference the one served by Facebook as you would any other script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'your app id',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```

Or you can load it asyncronously:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```